# How to pass List from Controller to View in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a List<> binded with some data in Controller action and I want to pass that List<> to View to bind with DataGrid in Razor View.

I am new to MVC.Can any one help me how to pass and how to access in View.

Comment: Summing up the answers so far. You can use for this: 1 - Using `View()`, 2 - Using `ViewData`, 3 - Using `ViewBag`, 4 - Using your custom `class`, and 5 - Some combinations of those approaches.

Answer (score 54):

Passing data to view is simple as passing object to method. Take a look at
[Controller.View Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492930.aspx)

```
protected internal ViewResult View(
    Object model
)
```

Something like this

```
//controller

List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>();

return View(list);


//view

@model List<MyObject>

// and property Model is type of List<MyObject>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <span>@item.Name</span>
}
```

Comment: Worked for me when I had `@Model` instead of `@model`.

Comment: what if you want to send 2 separate lists from controller to view?

Comment: Than you should create ViewModel class that has two List properties and pass instance of that class to view

Comment: is there are any way for fetch data without foreach loop and simply we write model => model.Data @archil

Answer (score 14):

I did this;

In controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var invoices = db.Invoices;

  var categories = db.Categories.ToList();
  ViewData["MyData"] = categories; // Send this list to the view

  return View(invoices.ToList());
}
```

In view:

```
@model IEnumerable<abc.Models.Invoice>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Invoices";
}

@{
  var categories = (List<Category>) ViewData["MyData"]; // Cast the list
}

@foreach (var c in @categories) // Print the list
{
  @Html.Label(c.Name);
}

<table>
    ...
    @foreach (var item in Model) 
    {
      ...
    }
</table>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: what if you want to send 2 separate lists to View from Controller?

Comment: Hi @RehanKhan, I think you should you make then 2 viewdata with 2 different names. ViewData["MyList1"] and ViewData["MyList2"] Best regards.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the dynamic object `ViewBag` to pass data from Controllers to Views.

Add the following to your controller:

```
ViewBag.MyList = myList;
```

Then you can acces it from your view:

```
@ViewBag.MyList

// e.g.
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.MyList) { ... }
```

Comment: This is the worst way data is passed from controller to view

Comment: Yes, but it's the easiest as well.

Comment: I would not agree. Magic strings with viewbag are easier than return View(model)?

Comment: It's complex magic in the background and surely not foolproof. But from a beginner's POV it's one of the simplest possible solutions. I like your answer better and will happily give it a +1 but will leave mine for reference.

Comment: I'm just critically against using viewbag/viewdata, and prefer using viewmodels :)

Comment: what is it with this line of code in your answer? `@ViewBag.MyList`. what is it doing?

Comment: one problem is maybe you fill ```@ViewBag.MyList``` with another lists and forget main subject.

Answer (score 6):

1. Create a model which contains your list and other things you need for the view.

   For example:

   ```
   public class MyModel
   {
       public List<string> _MyList { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. From the action method put your desired list to the Model, `_MyList` property, like:

   ```
   public ActionResult ArticleList(MyModel model)
   {
       model._MyList = new List<string>{"item1","item2","item3"};
       return PartialView(@"~/Views/Home/MyView.cshtml", model);
   }
   ```
3. In your view access the model as follows

   ```
   @model MyModel
   foreach (var item in Model)
   {
      <div>@item</div>
   }
   ```

I think it will help for start.

Comment: Nice approach. And you can pass as many list types as you want inside the model to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Here's Some ways to pass model list or data from controller to view in c# .net mvc

The First One using SelectListItem

Controller :

```
[HttpGet]
   public IActionResult Create()
   {
       IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list = context.Villas.ToList().Select(n => new SelectListItem
       {
           Text = n.Name,
           Value = n.Id.ToString()
       });

       ViewData["VillaList"] = list;

       return View();
   }
```

View :

```
<div class="form-floating py-1 col-12">
     <select asp-for="@Model.VillaId" asp-items="@ViewData["VillaList"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>" class="form-control border shadow" >
             <option disabled selected> Select Villa </option>
     </select>
     <label asp-for="VillaId" class="ms-2"></label>
     <span asp-validation-for="VillaId" class="text-danger"></span>
 </div>
```

The Second One using ViewBag for dynamic data

Controller :

```
[HttpGet]
  public IActionResult Create()
  {
      IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list = context.Villas.ToList().Select(n => new SelectListItem
      {
          Text = n.Name,
          Value = n.Id.ToString()
      });

      ViewBag.VillaList = list;

      return View();
  }
```

View :

```
<div class="form-floating py-1 col-12">
    <select asp-for="@Model.VillaId" asp-items="@ViewBag.VillaList" class="form-control border shadow">
            <option disabled selected> Select Villa </option>
    </select>
    <label asp-for="VillaId" class="ms-2"></label>
    <span asp-validation-for="VillaId" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```