# How to use a ViewBag to create a dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag, dropdownlistfor

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Filter()
{
    ViewBag.Accounts = BusinessLayer.AccountManager.Instance.getUserAccounts(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
<td>Account: </td>
<td>@Html.DropDownListFor("accountid", new SelectList(ViewBag.Accounts, "AccountID", "AccountName"))</td>
```

`ViewBag.Accounts` contains `Account` objects which have `AccountID`, `AccountName` and other properties.
I would like a `DropDownList` called **accountid** (so that on Form Post I can pass the selected AccountID) and the `DropDownList` to display the `AccountName` while having the `AccountID` as value.

What am I doing wrong in the view code?

Comment: View code is obviously not working/not good.

Comment: What does getUserAccounts return? Does it return collection of the object?

Comment: yes. IEnumerable<CommonLayer.Account>

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You cannot used the Helper `@Html.DropdownListFor`, because the first parameter was not correct, change your helper to:

```
@Html.DropDownList("accountid", new SelectList(ViewBag.Accounts, "AccountID", "AccountName"))
```

`@Html.DropDownListFor` receive in the first parameters a lambda expression in all overloads and is used to create strongly typed dropdowns.

[Here's the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

If your View it's strongly typed to some Model you may change your code using a helper to created a strongly typed dropdownlist, something like

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.accountId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Accounts, "AccountID", "AccountName"))
```

Comment: Thanks, I have changed it to the following: @Html.DropDownList("accountid", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Accounts)
however the name being displayed is the object name not the actual accounts names

Answer (score 27):

Try:

In the controller:

```
ViewBag.Accounts= new SelectList(db.Accounts, "AccountId", "AccountName");
```

In the View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("AccountId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Accounts, null, new { @class ="form-control" })
```

or you can replace the "null" with whatever you want display as default selector, i.e. "Select Account".

Comment: How do I retrieve the value from the `DropDownList` to the controller?

Answer (score 5):

I do the following

In my action method

```
    Dictionary<string, string> dictAccounts = ViewModelDropDown.GetAccounts(id);
    ViewBag.accounts = dictAccounts;
```

In my View Code

```
 Dictionary<string, string> accounts = (Dictionary<string, string>)ViewBag.accounts;
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AccountId, new SelectList(accounts, "Value", "Key"), new { style = "width:310px; height: 30px; padding 5px; margin: 5px 0 6px; background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF; vertical-align:middle;" })
```

Answer (score 3):

hope it will work

```
 @Html.DropDownList("accountid", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Accounts, String.Empty, new { @class ="extra-class" })
```

Here `String.Empty`  will be the empty as a default selector.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `@Html.DropDownList` instead:

```
<td>Account: </td>
<td>@Html.DropDownList("accountid", new SelectList(ViewBag.Accounts, "AccountID", "AccountName"))</td>
```

`@Html.DropDownListFor` expects a lambda as its first argument, not a `string` for the ID as you specify.

Other than that, without knowing what `getUserAccounts()` consists of, suffice to say it needs to return some sort of collection (`IEnumerable` for example) that has at least 1 object in it. If it returns `null` the property in the ViewBag won't have anything.

Answer (score 1):

[Marie McDonley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41188943/7389293) solution is good enough, but I've read comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10994833/7389293) saying that it is not a good approach. I made my own, very similar to [Marie's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41188943/7389293), but using [ViewData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.viewdatadictionary.-ctor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2).

Note: If you want to now more about `ViewData`, go to `System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase` or to `System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`.

## Solution Using `ViewData`

### Controller

```cs
List<SelectListItem> Lista= new List<SelectListItem>();

Lista.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select option", Value = "0", Selected = true });

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    string j = String.Format("{0}", i);
    Lista.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = j, Value = j });
}

ViewData["YourList"] = Lista;
```

### View

```cs
@Html.DropDownList(
    "id_for_select_element", // eg: "yourId", the name of the form field
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["YourList"], // your list items
    "option_label", // eg: "Select Value"
                    // if null, you can place your own text at value 0
                    // as I did above.
    new { @class = "form-control form-select" } // object for html attributes
                                                // In this case, those are Bootstrap classes
)
```

### Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Use Viewbag is wrong for sending list to view.You should using Viewmodel in this case. like this:**

### Send Country list and City list and Other list you need to show in View:

### HomeController Code:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult NewAgahi() // New Advertising
        {
            //--------------------------------------------------------
            // استفاده از ویومدل برای نمایش چند مدل در ویو
            Country_Repository blCountry = new Country_Repository();
            Ostan_Repository blOstan = new Ostan_Repository();
            City_Repository blCity = new City_Repository();
            Mahale_Repository blMahale = new Mahale_Repository();
            Agahi_Repository blAgahi = new Agahi_Repository();

            var vm = new NewAgahi_ViewModel();
            vm.Country = blCountry.Select();
            vm.Ostan = blOstan.Select();
            vm.City = blCity.Select();
            vm.Mahale = blMahale.Select();
            //vm.Agahi = blAgahi.Select();

            return View(vm);
        }

        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult NewAgahi(Agahi agahi)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid == true)
            {
                Agahi_Repository blAgahi = new Agahi_Repository();

                agahi.Date = DateTime.Now.Date;
                agahi.UserId = 1048;
                agahi.GroupId = 1;


                if (blAgahi.Add(agahi) == true)
                {
                    //Success
                    return JavaScript("alert('ثبت شد')");

                }
                else
                {
                    //Fail
                    return JavaScript("alert('اشکال در ثبت')");

            }
```

---

### Viewmodel Code:

```
using ProjectName.Models.DomainModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ProjectName.ViewModels
{
    public class NewAgahi_ViewModel // برای استفاده کردن از چند مدل در یک ویو
    { 

        public IEnumerable<Country> Country { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Ostan> Ostan { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<City> City { get; set; }

        public IQueryable<Mahale> Mahale { get; set; }

        public ProjectName.Models.DomainModels.Agahi Agahi { get; set; }

    }
}
```

---

### View Code:

```
@model ProjectName.ViewModels.NewAgahi_ViewModel
```

.....
.....

```
@Html.DropDownList("CountryList", new SelectList(Model.Country, "id", "Name"))

 @Html.DropDownList("CityList", new SelectList(Model.City, "id", "Name"))
```

---

### Country_Repository Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using ProjectName.Models.DomainModels;

namespace ProjectName.Models.Repositories
{
    public class Country_Repository : IDisposable
    {
        private MyWebSiteDBEntities db = null;


        public Country_Repository()
        {
            db = new DomainModels.MyWebSiteDBEntities();
        }

        public Boolean Add(Country entity, bool autoSave = true)
        {
            try
            {
                db.Country.Add(entity);
                if (autoSave)
                    return Convert.ToBoolean(db.SaveChanges()); 
                                                                //return "True";
                else
                    return false;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string ss = e.Message;
                //return e.Message;
                return false;
            }
        }


        public bool Update(Country entity, bool autoSave = true)
        {
            try
            {
                db.Country.Attach(entity);
                db.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                if (autoSave)
                    return Convert.ToBoolean(db.SaveChanges());
                else
                    return false;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string ss = e.Message; // کد بلااستفاده فقط برای ازمایش اکسپشن این را نوشتم

                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool Delete(Country entity, bool autoSave = true)
        {
            try
            {
                db.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
                if (autoSave)
                    return Convert.ToBoolean(db.SaveChanges());
                else
                    return false;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool Delete(int id, bool autoSave = true)
        {
            try
            {
                var entity = db.Country.Find(id);
                db.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
                if (autoSave)
                    return Convert.ToBoolean(db.SaveChanges());
                else
                    return false;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public Country Find(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                return db.Country.Find(id);
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }


        public IQueryable<Country> Where(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Country, bool>> predicate)
        {
            try
            {
                return db.Country.Where(predicate);
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public IQueryable<Country> Select()
        {
            try
            {
                return db.Country.AsQueryable();
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public IQueryable<TResult> Select<TResult>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Country, TResult>> selector)
        {
            try
            {
                return db.Country.Select(selector);
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public int GetLastIdentity()
        {
            try
            {
                if (db.Country.Any())
                    return db.Country.OrderByDescending(p => p.id).First().id;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
            catch
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        public int Save()
        {
            try
            {
                return db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (this.db != null)
                {
                    this.db.Dispose();
                    this.db = null;
                }
            }
        }

        ~Country_Repository()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Departments.id, (SelectList)ViewBag.Department, "Select", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: I do the following

Answer (score -1):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Item 1", Value = "1" });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Item 2", Value = "2" });
    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Item 3", Value = "3" });

    
    ViewBag.Items = items;

    return View();
}

@Html.DropDownList("dropdownList", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Items)
```