# Is there a way to populate a combobox with values from a look up table using ASP.NET and Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

Let's say I have an entity named `Animal` which has a column called `Type` and it is a foreign key to a lookup table. I need a strongly typed relation between the view and `Animal`. How do I get the values stored in the lookup table into my view, so I can populate a combobox with the values from `Type`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a ViewBag to create a dropdownlist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594958/how-to-use-a-viewbag-to-create-a-dropdownlist)

Answer (score 0):

Operating with DB entity in the view is not the best approach from architectural point of view. It will be better if you create a separate ViewModel for that and use it in your view. For example, here is your DB entities:

```
public class Animal
{
    public int Type { get; set; }
}
public class AnimalType
{
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And here is your ViewModel:

```
public class AnimalViewModel
{
    public IDictionary<int, string> Animals { get; set; }
}
```

So in controller/service you can get your Animals and their type names (using Entity Framework navigation property or direct JOIN), create your ViewModel and pass to the view.