# Passing value to select list in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selectlist

I am trying to pass a concatenated columns from a LINQ statement to a select list using view bag.

Controller:

```
var translators = bidsinfo1.Select(x => new { Name = x.TranslatorFirstName + " " + x.TranslatorLastName} ).ToList();
ViewBag.TranslatorList = translators;
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <select class="form-control" asp-items="new SelectList(ViewBag.TranslatorList)">
                    <option>Select Translator</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

But in the select list when i run the project it's showing the values like this { Name = harvey specter }, please any suggestion?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16595386/125981 should help you here perhaps

Answer (score 0):

u should convert  List(of oBject) to a List(of String) and pass it to viewBag
so change your linqQuery to

```
var translators = bidsinfo1.Select(x =>  x.TranslatorFirstName + " " + x.TranslatorLastName ).ToList();
```

GoodLuck.

Answer (score 0):

i tried this and it's work now..

```
var translators = bidsinfo1.Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Name = x.TranslatorFirstName + " " + x.TranslatorLastName });
ViewBag.TranslatorList = new SelectList(translators, "Id", "Name");
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.TranslatorList">
        <option>Select Translator</option>
    </select>
</div>
```