# I can't send Create data to the db_context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to develop a cattle insemination control system (it's a kind of birth control, where I have data such as the birth of calves, the names of their mothers, fathers...) in ASP.NET MVC, with Entity Framework (at the end of the question there is the relational model generated by it).

The problem is that I can't save my create data to the database, I get the following error:

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Vaca_IDRaca". The conflict occurred in the database "ControleInseminacao", table "dbo.IDRaca", column 'IDRaca'.

In the table test I did, I noticed that I am not receiving the data selected in the drop-down list, where would my error be?

The `Vaca` table is linked to two other tables, my view even displays data from both in my drop-down list, but I was unable to save this information in my database.

My controller:

```
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult Create()
  {
      ControleInseminacaoEntities1 db_context = new ControleInseminacaoEntities1();

      ViewBag.ListaFazendas = new SelectList(db_context.Fazenda.ToList(), "IDFazenda", "Name");
      ViewBag.ListaRacas = new SelectList(db_context.IDRaca.ToList(), "IDRaca1", "Name");

      return View();
  }

  [HttpPost]
  Public ActionResult Create(Cow cow)
  {
      ControleInseminacaoEntities1 db_context = new ControleInseminacaoEntities1();

      db_context.Cow.Add(cow);
      db_context.SaveChanges();

      return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
```

And my view:

```
    @model ControleInseminacao.net.Models.Vaca

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Vaca</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        Fazenda
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Fazenda", ViewBag.ListaFazendas as SelectList, "Selecione uma Fazenda", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FK_Vaca_IDFazenda, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        Raça
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("IDRaca", ViewBag.ListaRacas as SelectList, "Selecione uma raça", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FK_Vaca_IDRaca, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

I apologize for any typos, I'm Brazilian and speak Portuguese, however, no one on the Brazilian forum answered my question...

My database:

[image: My database]

I created another model, also new columns and relationships, I also changed the controller several times, but nothing works, in the line-by-line test I was able to see that I can't add it to the database because I don't receive the data from my view. I would like to know where I am going wrong.

my database creation script:

```
    USE [ControleInseminacao]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Bezerro]    Script Date: 20/12/2023 08:28:55 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bezerro](
    [Sexo] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [FK_Bezerro_IDRaca] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DataNascimento] [date] NOT NULL,
    [FK_Bezerro_IDIns] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FK_Bezerro_IDRep] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IDBezerro] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FK_Bezerro_IDVaca] [int] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IDBezerro] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Fazenda]    Script Date: 20/12/2023 08:28:55 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Fazenda](
    [Nome] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IDFazenda] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IDFazenda] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[IDRaca]    Script Date: 20/12/2023 08:28:55 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IDRaca](
    [IDRaca] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Nome] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_IDRaca] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IDRaca] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Inseminacao]    Script Date: 20/12/2023 08:28:55 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Inseminacao](
    [FK_Inseminacao_IDRep] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FK_Inseminacao_IDFazenda] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IDInseminacao] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FK_Inseminacao_IDVaca] [int] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IDInseminacao] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Reprodutor]    Script Date: 20/12/2023 08:28:55 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Reprodutor](
    [Nome] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FK_Rep_IDRaca] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FK_Rep_IDFazenda] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IDRep] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IDRep] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Vaca]    Script Date: 20/12/2023 08:28:55 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Vaca](
    [FK_Vaca_IDRaca] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IDVaca] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Nome] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FK_Vaca_IDFazenda] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IDVaca] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Bezerro]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Bezerro_IDRaca] FOREIGN KEY([FK_Bezerro_IDRaca])
REFERENCES [dbo].[IDRaca] ([IDRaca])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Bezerro] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Bezerro_IDRaca]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Bezerro]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Bezerro_IDVaca] FOREIGN KEY([FK_Bezerro_IDVaca])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Vaca] ([IDVaca])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Bezerro] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Bezerro_IDVaca]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Bezerro]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Bezerro_Inseminacao] FOREIGN KEY([FK_Bezerro_IDIns])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Inseminacao] ([IDInseminacao])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Bezerro] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Bezerro_Inseminacao]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Bezerro]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Bezerro_Reprodutor] FOREIGN KEY([FK_Bezerro_IDRep])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Reprodutor] ([IDRep])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Bezerro] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Bezerro_Reprodutor]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Inseminacao]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Inseminacao_Fazenda] FOREIGN KEY([FK_Inseminacao_IDFazenda])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Fazenda] ([IDFazenda])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Inseminacao] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Inseminacao_Fazenda]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Inseminacao]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Inseminacao_Reprodutor] FOREIGN KEY([FK_Inseminacao_IDRep])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Reprodutor] ([IDRep])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Inseminacao] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Inseminacao_Reprodutor]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Inseminacao]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Inseminacao_Vaca] FOREIGN KEY([FK_Inseminacao_IDVaca])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Vaca] ([IDVaca])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Inseminacao] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Inseminacao_Vaca]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Reprodutor]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Rep_IDFazenda] FOREIGN KEY([FK_Rep_IDFazenda])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Fazenda] ([IDFazenda])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Reprodutor] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Rep_IDFazenda]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Reprodutor]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Reprodutor_IDRaca] FOREIGN KEY([FK_Rep_IDRaca])
REFERENCES [dbo].[IDRaca] ([IDRaca])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Reprodutor] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Reprodutor_IDRaca]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Vaca]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Vaca_IDFazenda] FOREIGN KEY([FK_Vaca_IDFazenda])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Fazenda] ([IDFazenda])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Vaca] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Vaca_IDFazenda]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Vaca]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Vaca_IDRaca] FOREIGN KEY([FK_Vaca_IDRaca])
REFERENCES [dbo].[IDRaca] ([IDRaca])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Vaca] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Vaca_IDRaca]
GO
```

Comment: Is it correct that **`bank`** is a **DbContext** instance? In all projects I ever did it is customary to *name* it `dbContext`, `_dbContext` or `_context` so everyone will easily recognize it as such. I recommend you to at least update the Question Title for clarity. Bank is usually a financial institute...

Comment: yes, it is an instance, but would this affect my code?

Comment: It was not clear at all from the code, because you also gave no defintion of class ControleInseminacaoEntities1. It is clear now, at least for those who read these comments (not everybody may do so) and because of that I still recommend you fix the Title (AFAIK using the word Bank is never normal in the English language for this purpose).

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will modify my question.

Comment: Probably the usual error: an id value not coming back from the UI, i.e. you try to post a foreign key value = 0.

Comment: Please provide your view model as well.  Looks like since you are using viewbag, you are not binding back to the model.  Also, you have Vaca as the view model defined in view and Cow as the model you are posting.  Is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

You have a foreign key constraint error between table [Vaca] and table [IdRaca].  You cannot insert into table [Vaca] without a matching record in table [IRaca]

For Example:

If you are trying to insert the following into table [Vaca]

[image]

You need to have a record in table [IdRaca] with matching value (highlighted).
[image]

**UPDATE**
I am not seeing where the value from the DropDownList is binding to the view model property.  Try using DropDownListFor instead.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FK_Vaca_IDFazenda, ViewBag.ListaFazendas, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16595386/11376319

Comment: I appreciate the help, but the problem is that I'm not receiving the value to save the data in my database, in my view I can select IDRaca1 in my dropdownlist, but this information is being passed as null, I would like to know why what...

Comment: Can you show more of the cshtml view, from top to bottom? Also, if you are using any javascript to post to the MVC controller, please include the javascript Http Post call in your question. I would like to see how you are posting back to the server.

Comment: I added my complete view to the question, I made some changes to include a list with some data in it, but it is already generated by ASP .NET itself

Comment: I added some update notes to the answer with example of using DropDownListFor to bind the value to the view model property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm still trying to solve it, I tried this way: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IDRaca, ViewBag.ListaRacas as SelectList, "Select a race", new { @class = "form-control" }), But it still didn't work

Comment: I'm sorry these are not working for you.  I do want to point out that you should have a separate view model from your entity framework model and then map them for best practices.

Comment: Thank you again for your help, I already have a better defined path to research now

Answer (score 0):

@Stephen Raman
I ACHIEVED !!! I modified it to

```
 <div class="form-group">
    Race
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("FK_VACA_IDRACA", ViewBag.ListaRacas as SelectList, "Select a breed", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FK_VACA_IDRACA, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

apparently I was unable to collect this data correctly in the visualization itself