# How to pass List from backend to front end in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Hi I have been trying for the last hour to connect my c# backend to the front-end to output a list.
I have always wondered what about the best way to pass data from backend to front-end.

In my scenario I only want to output a simple list from in mvc, but how do I send my list to the frontend so I can do something simple as outputting all the data in a table with something like a foreach:

```
foreach (var value in customerList) {
<p>value.Name</p>
}
```

I have looked at the solution suggested in this link: [How to pass List from Controller to View in MVC 3.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994790/how-to-pass-list-from-controller-to-view-in-mvc-3) by archil

but I can’t figure out where to put 
protected internal ViewResult View(
    Object model
)

So how can I output my list?
I know the list contains content as I have put a breakpoint and stepped through it.

This is how my code looks like:

```
    public List<Customer> customerList = new List<Customer>();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var client = new CustomerAzureAPIApp();
        var response = client.Customer.Get();
        var customers = response;

        foreach (var customer in customers)
        {
            customerList.Add(customer);
        }

        return View();
}
```

I know I can use ViewBag, but I don’t want to create a new ViewBag for each item in the list, I would rather just send the whole list. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I don’t know about the best solution, but don’t get confused about the code suggested by archil in the link you provided.

You simply could just pass your customerList with the

```
return View(customerList);
```

as an argument because that line of code automatically creates a ViewResult object by using the model that renders a view to response.

So in your front-end you could end up doing something like this for your table:

```
<table
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Name</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Remember to have “@” before your item because we are dealing with Razor view-engine.

Answer (score 1):

As said previously you can use the Model by returning the list in the view

```
return View(*insert list here*);
```

and than in your view :

```
@model List<*insertTypehere*>
```

and in your foreach you would use the variable name

```
Model
```

There's another way by not returning anything in the view and using the Viewbag,in your controller.

```
Viewbag.TheNameYouWish = *insert list*
```

and in your view you could use :

```
@Viewbag.TheNameYouWish
```

so either

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
```

or

```
@foreach (var item in @Viewbag.TheNameYouWish)
```

does the job.

Answer (score 0):

In you view you have declare the model to which it should be binded, and then iterate over it:

```
@model  List<Customer>

@foreach (var value in Model) {
<p>value.Name</p>
}
```

The sceond thing you need to pass your list back to view from action, so change the following :

```
return View();
```

to :

```
 return View(customerList);
```