# Pass List From Controller to View Using ViewBag

Tags: c#, html, sql, model-view-controller, razor

From Controller I am passing a list of AccountNumbers using ViewBag to the View, and this is running well

Controller Code:

```
  List<AccountNumberSum> my_output_list = new List<AccountNumberSum>();
      my_output_list.Add(new AccountNumberSum { 
                                                 account_number = oo.CreditAccountNumber,
                                                  total_amount = item1.Amount.Value
                                            });
      var grouped_data = my_output_list.GroupBy(x => x.account_number)
                    .Select(x => new { account_number = x.Key, total_amount = x.Sum(y=> y.total_amount) })
                    .ToList();


           ViewBag.grouped_data = grouped_data.Count();
```

And View Code For this is :

```
@if (ViewBag.grouped_data != null)
{

    <div class="tb">
        <table id="table_id" class="display" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th>
                        Sl.No
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Account Number
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Total Amount
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.grouped_data.GetType().GetProperties())


            {

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @item.account_number



                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.total_amount

                    </td>


                </tr>
            }

        </table>
    </div>
```

}
I am getting the following error:
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable''. I want to show account numbers,Total_amount in Table in view using ViewBag.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are passing the count, which is int and that you are treating it as `IEnunerable` in the view. Pass it without applying `Count()`.

Comment: when i Skip count(),i get following error in view Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''object' does not contain a definition for 'account_number''

Comment: Don't use like this ViewBag.grouped_data.GetType().GetProperties()) . Use like this ViewBag.grouped_data

Comment: I did using View.Bag.Grouped_data still iget Object does not contain a definiation for account number

Comment: Check the spelling and case

Comment: Use like this `@ViewBag.MyList

// e.g.
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.MyList) { ... }`

Comment: I would suggest to use model instead of ViewBag if you can. Here is example https://stackoverflow.com/a/10994916/6527049

Comment: Can you put breakpoint and see what value are you getting in the view

Comment: im Getting the expected data from my Database after putting breakpoint but i cant show it in view.

Comment: Is account number public or private?

Comment: Both are Public i mean account_number abd totalAmount.