# How can I Display inner join table on ASP.NET(Web app) using Ado.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I have already made a SQL string for innerjoin the  2 tables I want

This is from DataAceess layer

```
  public void showTable()
        {
            string queryString = " Select Product.name, Product.price,ShoppingCart.Count " + "From Product" +
                 " INNER JOIN ShoppingCart On Product.ID = ShoppingCart.ProductId";

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand readCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, con))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader shoppingCartReader = readCommand.ExecuteReader();
               

            }
            

        }
```

This is from Controller

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Index()

        {
            /*
            shoppingcart = new ShoppingCartViewModel()
            {
                ListCart = dataacc.getAll()
            }; */
            var showTable = dataacc.showTable();

            return View();
        }
```

This is from .cshtml

> 

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Order information</h1>

<hr />



<div>

    <div class="col-md-2"> 
    <form asp-action="Index">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Customer.FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Customer.FirstName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ID" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Customer.LastName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Customer.LastName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="customerId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="orderDate" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="orderDate" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="orderDate" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

    </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">
        
        <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Selected Amount</th>
                <th>Menu</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Subtotal</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
```

I don't know what to do next, i can't convert my query to a list. Hopes someone know this Thank you for helping :D

I tried to make queries and convert to list using var but it didn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass List from Controller to View in MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994790/how-to-pass-list-from-controller-to-view-in-mvc-3)

Comment: What's  the value of   showTable in  `var showTable = dataacc.showTable(); ` ?